# Objective C: Touch Draw On UIScrollView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer, uitouch

I am trying to make a drawing book app with different pages on it using a pageEnabled UIScrollView.

What am i gonna use?? touch events are not working.

i have this code before on touches moved:

```
    touchSwiped = YES;

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];   
    CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    currentPoint.y -= 20;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
    [drawView.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, drawView.frame.size.width, drawView.frame.size.height)];
    CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 15.0);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0, 0, 0, 1.0);
    CGContextBeginPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    drawView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    lastPoint = currentPoint;

    touchMoved++;

    if (touchMoved == 10) {
        touchMoved = 0;
    }
```

i don't have any idea what adjustments i need to do in order to implement this.

anyone??

thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are drawing on a UIScrollView, how does the scroll view know if a touch is to draw or to scroll?

Comment: i tried it using the UIPanGesture

Comment: When you say "touch events are not working", what do you mean exactly? It scrolls instead of drawing? Or touches are not being captured at all? Remember that for it to scroll, the content size has to be bigger than its frame size.

Comment: it scrolls instead of drawing... i've tried everything i know and up to now it's not solved...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a UIPanGestureRecognizer as mentioned in your comments, then you have set the minimumNumberOfTouches to something greater than 1, right? Otherwise, how does it tell the difference between drawing and scrolling?

My recommendations are:

1. Do not use a UIScrollView unless you first figure out a way to conclusively determine if a touch is for drawing or for scrolling as intended by the user. Use a subclass of UIView instead, and then maybe use buttons to move between pages.
2. Or you could have a button that toggles between drawing and scrolling (paging) between the pages of your scroll view.
3. Check out this website for some tips and actual code to do the drawing http://www.ifans.com/forums/showthread.php?t=132024